# Is Ubuntu installed on the same partition as my data?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

[GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQO8m.png)My laptop is running terribly and I don't know whether I'm experience a HDD failure or an issue with 14.04 LTS. I'm a novice and am hoping to move my data to a backup drive, but it's moving so slowly that I feel it could take a week to complete the task.

Alternately, I was thinking of trying to reinstall Ubuntu. However, I'm unsure whether my data and OS are on separate partitions, so I don't know if it's safe.

Could someone please look at the attached screenshots and let me know (1) if my data and OS are on the same partitions and (2) what the red exclamation point means?

Thanks!

```
123@15R:~$ df
Filesystem         1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                 8137012         4   8137008   1% /dev
tmpfs                1630664      1096   1629568   1% /run
/dev/dm-1          944624036 798146920  98469948  90% /
none                       4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                    5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                 8153300     30432   8122868   1% /run/shm
none                  102400        56    102344   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1             240972     55421    173110  25% /boot
/home/123/.Private 944624036 798146920  98469948  90% /home/123
123@15R:~
```

Comment: No screenshots are present in this post. Maybe something went wrong while attaching them? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: For terminal output, please don't use screenshots. Instead, copy and paste the terminal output into your question, select it with your mouse, and press the `{}` button in the question editor.

Comment: You seem to be showing an encrypted /home. so you must always have good regular backups of encrypted /home. If passphrase is damaged or stops working for any reason you will not be able to get any data. I would not reinstall until you have fully backed up.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify a special setup during install every version of Ubuntu has defaulted to installing all data on the same partition. You would have had to use the advanced or "custom" partition layout options while installing to get a setup where `/` and `/home` are on different partitions.

Since your disk may be failing doing a full copy could stress it into failing entirely. My advice is copy the most important files *first* while making the backup. I suggest using `rsync` to do this. First mount your backup disk somwehere (you should see it's location in the file browser by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) like `/media/mybackupdisk` then run this command to start copying your files:

```
rsync -r ~ /media/mybackupdisk
```

This tells `rsync` to copy all data from your home directory (`~`) to your backup disk. The `rsync` tool is smart enough to avoid duplicate transfers if interrupted. If you want to see more information about the transfer change `rsync` to `rsync --progress`

Comment: I attempted to add the GParted image and also to correct the improper formatting of the output. Apologies for the formatting issues. Does the Gparted screenshot confirm whether my data is on a dedicated partition?

Comment: Your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQO8m.png) shows you're using LUKS for an encrypted disk, so it's not easy to tell if you have an entire disk encrypted or a separate partition for your home directory. My advice is use `rsync` to backup your data manually first since migrating that partition outside of the LUKS container and installing Linux within it will be a bit tricky.

Comment: thank you very much. I will attempt to back up my data manually as you and oldfred have suggested. Thank you for your assistance.